# lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jtermios.windows.WinAPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when  i run my api ,1st time its giving the correct response ,after again calling the api i am getting below error.
I am using java 8.

if i restart the server 1st time it will working fine. the same code working fine all time in my company laptop. i dont konw what i missed it in the personal laptop

```
{ "errorCode": 400, "message": "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jtermios.windows.WinAPI" }
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml file

Comment: its only problem with the particular laptop not other laptop

Comment: See here: https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm/issues/124